# JsonElement Parameter has valuekind undefined even after passing data?

Tags: asp.net, json, jsonelement

I created a method that takes in a JSONElement parameter. The problem is that whenever I execute the method and pass it a json object, the parameter is always of value undefined.

Why is this happening?

The following is the method that I am trying to work with:

```
public string GetJsonElement(JsonElement data)
        {
          return "Done";
        }
```

Whenever I put breakpoints in my code to check the data parameter's value, this keeps showing up:

> data  ValueKind = Undefined : ""  System.Text.Json.JsonElement

The Json I am passing:

```
{
"User":"User1",
"FullName":"Jane Doe"
}
```

Could someone shed some light on what is happening and how I can maybe get rid of the problem please?

Comment: How are you passing json object to this method.Can you share that snippet as well

Comment: I have shared the json i am passing in the question as it doesn't show clearly here

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by removing newtonsoft as my serializer for mvc from startup

Comment: if you add some sample code that would be better to understanding